# Number of reduced decompositions of the longest element of the Weyl group

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

Let $R$ be a reduced root system, $W$ the associated Weyl group, and $w_0 \in W$ the longest element of $W$. In general $w_0$ admits more than one reduced decomposition into a product of reflections, a number which we denote by $d_R$. Where can one find a list of values of $d_R$ for low-dimensional root systems?

For example are the explicit values of $d_R$ known for the exceptional root systems?

Comment: For Types A and B(=C) there are product formulas for these numbers: see the famous paper http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/56.pdf and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271510/the-number-of-reduced-expressions-for-the-longest-element-of-b-n. I'm pretty sure for Type D there is *not* a product formula (as Stanley mentions there is a big prime, 193, in the factorization of the number of reduced words of the longest word in Type $D_4$). As for exceptionals I don't know of a list but this is in principle something a computer can do.

Comment: In the linked stackexchange webpage the B-series formula in the answer gives, for low values of $n$, a product with negative limits. Is this an error or is this an example of some  convention I am not familar with? For example, what is the value for $B_2$?

Comment: Maybe the formula Zach wrote is not quite right. For $B_2$ the answer should be 2. It is the same as the number of linear extensions of the root poset (poset of positive roots whereby $\alpha \leq \beta$ if $\beta-\alpha$ is a nonnegative sum of simple roots). This poset is the same as the shifted trapezoid shape $(2n-1,2n-3,...,1)$ poset. This number also happens to be the same as the number of SYTs of $n\times n$ square shape.

Comment: You can see Corollary 5.2 of the paper of Stanley linked above for another way of writing the product formula for the Type B # of reduced decompositions (he lists it as a conjecture but it has been proven).

Comment: The basic thing that's going on here is that there's an Edelman-Greene style bijection in Types A and B (and also the non-Weyl types $I_2(m)$ and $H_3$- sometimes these types are called the 'coincidental types'). The other types don't have such a bijection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy to do in [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/). E.g. the following code

```
G = WeylGroup("F4")
w = G.long_element_hardcoded()
print(w)
rw = w.reduced_words() 
len(rw)
```

outputs 2144892. If you want to look at some of these reduced words just examine the list rw. To create a list for classical types of different rank do

```
res = {}
for n in range(2,5):
    G = WeylGroup(["A", n])
    w = G.long_element_hardcoded()
    print("Calculating rank ", n)
    res[n] = len(w.reduced_words())
```

Comment: Note 2144892 = 2^2 x 3 x 47 x 3803, again suggesting lack of product formula.

Comment: I created http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001585. If you have enough power to do E6 that would be great!

Comment: @MartinRubey I will try some computer in Prague's Charles University to which I have remote access. But I am pessimistic. This algorithm actually generates and stores all the reduced words so it eats all available memory rather quickly.

Comment: Counting reduced words is the same as counting directed paths between two vertices in a certain directed graph (the weak order graph), so it's possible you could write code by hand that does this faster than what's in Sage.

Comment: @SamHopkins Actually, SageMath implements this via BraidOrbit and includes a TODO that promises counting the number of reduced words to be much faster. It's a bit outside of my expertise and I have enough work on my plate to dig into this right now. If no better answer shows up, feel free to ping me in a week or two.

Comment: @SamHopkins, indeed, this is much faster!  I added corresponding code to the findstat entry.  $D_5$ is now easy.  Unfortunately, FindStat has a limitation on the size of statistic values, so anything beyond $A_6$ is too large.

Comment: It would be nice if this number would have a (large) natural (that is, predictable) factor.

Comment: @MartinRubey I gave it a shot but the $E_6$ calculation doesn't fit into 16  GB of RAM and I don't have access to more.

Comment: Did you try the code from findstat? This should not take much memory.

Comment: @MartinRubey Of course. The problem is that the weak poset doesn't fit into the memory. Is it possible to reimplement the chain polynomial of weak poset using weak_order_ideal method of the WeylGroup object?

Answer (score 7):

Around the time Fomin and I wrote [this
paper](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/94.pdf), Tao Kai Lam applied the technique to type $D_n$. It
emerged that it was "natural" to weight a reduced
decomposition $\rho$ by $2^{d(\rho)}$, where $d(\rho)$ is
the number of simple reflections in $\rho$ that correspond
to the $n-2$ "nonbranch nodes" in the Coxeter diagram for
$D_n$. Using this weighting, there is a
nice product formula for the number of weighted reduced
decompositions of the longest element, which I unfortunately
have forgotten. I hope someone can redo this work.

Comment: Is this weighted sum related to linear extensions in some way?

Comment: @SamHopkins: I have a hazy recollection that it is a power of 2 times the number of SYT of the shifted shape $(2n-2,2n-4,\dots,4,2)$ (for which there is a nice product formula).

Comment: That would make a lot of sense! In https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/159973/Williams_umn_0130E_14358.pdf Williams calls the poset you're talking about the "flattened root poset" of $D_n$.

Comment: Actually, the result you mention might follow from this paper of Billey and Haiman: https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/schubert/schubert.pdf (see also the discussion on pg. 46 of the thesis of Williams linked above)

Comment: Name of this paper: [Schubert polynomials and the nilCoxeter algebra](https://doi.org/10.1006/aima.1994.1009).