# One element commutation classes of reduced decompositions of the longest element of the Weyl group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

For the symmetric group on $n$ objects $S_n$ the question of how to write its longest element $w_0$ as a reduced decomposition is an important combinatorical problem. As example, in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370333/number-of-reduced-decompositions-of-the-longest-element-of-the-weyl-group) the number of such decompositions is discussed.

Following [Stembridge](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022452717148), we define a relation $∼$ on the set of reduced expressions for $w_0$. Let $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{w}'$ be two reduced expressions for $w_0$ and define $\mathbf{w} \sim \mathbf{w}'$ if we can obtain $\mathbf{w}'$ from $\mathbf{w}$ by applying a single commutation. Now, define the equivalence relation $\simeq$ by taking the reflexive transitive
closure of $\sim$. Each equivalence class under $\simeq$ is called a commutation class.

The question of the number of commutation classes (of reduced expressions for $w_0 \in S_n$) is still an open problem. However, is there an formula for the number of equivalence classes containing just one element?

Comment: Do you mean that you consider $S_n$ as a Coxeter group with generating set $s_1 = (12)$, $s_2 = (23)$, $s_3 = (34)$, etc.? What do you mean by a "single commutation"? Do you mean that you replace a single instance of $s_i s_j$ by $s_j s_i$ where $s_i$ and $s_j$ are commuting generators?

Comment: @TomDeMedts: yes, and this set-up is very common, so I think the question is clear as it is.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but sort of related: there has been work done on computing the *expected number of braid moves* that one can apply to a random reduced expression for $w_0$: see Reiner (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2004.06.010), Tenner (https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/62/ajc_v62_p147.pdf), Schilling et al. (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2016.10.008)

Comment: Opening this question, I was curious what the Weyl group with one element was

Comment: With regard to it being an "open question" how many commutation classes there are, we at least know specific values up to $n=16$, see https://oeis.org/A006245, where there is also some Maple code I posted for computing it (I was the first one to compute a(12)). In terms of a closed form, which might be what you consider the "open" part of the question, given how difficult it has been to find the first $16$ values I'd bet a lot of money that there's no closed form expression for this number. It has a lot of combinatorial interpretations and I think it is sharp-P hard to compute it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reduced words that are in their own commutation classes are:

- $s = [123\cdots(n-2)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots321][23\cdots(n-3)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots32][3\cdots(n-4)(n-3)(n-4)\cdots3]\cdots$
- the reversal of $s$ (writing the word in reverse order)
- the complement of $s$ (mapping each letter $i$ to $n-i$)
- the reverse complement of $s$

This is just one word in $S_2$ and two words in $S_3$ (no big surprises there!). Otherwise it is four words. For example, in $S_6$, they are

- 123454321234323
- 323432123454321
- 543212345432343
- 343234543212345

On a separate note, to add to the list of related topics, you might want to look at Fishel et al. (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2018.07.002) about how commutation classes and braid classes interact.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that for $n \geq 4$ there will be exactly $4$ such reduced words. One such word, call it $R_n$ can be constructed by starting with $s_{n-1}s_{n-2} \cdots s_2s_1s_2 \cdots s_{n-2}s_{n-1}$ and appending $R_{n-1}$ with all indices shifted up by 1. For example, $$R_6=s_5s_4s_3s_2s_1s_2s_3s_4s_5s_4s_3s_2s_3s_4s_3.$$
Three more words can be obtained by replacing each $s_i$ with $s_{n-i}$, reversing the word, or doing both.

For $n=4,5,6$ these are the only possibilities, and this probably shouldn't be too hard to argue in general.